# Extend existing application to multiple data centers

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, cloud

Currently, we have running our application in one of AWS Region/data centers. Are there any strategies or principles we can follow to extends our application to another data center?

How we can quickly bring up the same or minimum set of services/AWS-stack to another region quickly?
Do any trade-offs need to be considered?

Current AWS resources in existing DC: EC2, S3, Dynamodb, RDS, VPC, security groups, ELB, Lambda, API G/W

Comment: By "data center" you mean an single aws availability zone, or aws region?

Comment: Its aws region. I meant to bring up quickly something in another region.

Answer (score 1):

All of the services you have listed (except for Amazon EC2) **automatically run across multiple Availability Zones within the Region**. This means that, if an AZ fails, those services are *not* impacted.

An **Availability Zone** is a physically separate data center within the Region. It is sufficiently distant and has different networking such that a failure in one AZ should not impact another AZ. Running your services across multiple AZs should be sufficient for high-availability rather than running across multiple Regions.

Each Amazon EC2 instance, however, resides in only one AZ since it is a virtual machine running on a single host computer. To make your application highly-available, you should:

- Run EC2 across **at least two AZs**
- Configure the **Elastic Load Balancer** to distribute traffic across all of those instances

This way, if an AZ fails and the EC2 instances in that AZ are not available, the app will continue to run in the other AZs.

**Amazon RDS offers multi-AZ capabilities** if you choose '**multi-AZ**' when launching the database. This will run a primary database in one AZ and a secondary database in another AZ. If the primary AZ fails, the secondary database will take over. The data is automatically replicated to the secondary database, so no data will be lost. (Extra charges apply for this feature.)

There is lots of information available online on this topic. Just search for "aws multiple AZs".

Comment: Thanks, John for the quick response. Let's say the application running into the US wet and we want to extend it to the APAC region then are there any strategies we should use? How we can quickly bring another region up with minimal efforts?

Comment: Can I ask what is your actual goal? Is it redundancy in case of failure, or wanting to be closer to your users? Using multiple AZs should be sufficient for redundancy (Oregon has 4 AZs!). Running across multiple regions is _much_ more difficult because none of the services you mention will automatically run across multiple Regions. You would be responsible for replicating data (which is expensive!), detecting failure and switching-over traffic to an alternate region. [Netflix does it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAyA86QGRnI) but it is hard.

Comment: The goal is to get the redundancy across region in case of failure.

Comment: @Neel Your goal might be to have redundancy, but saying "redundancy across region" is a _how_, not a _why_. Using multiple AZs can provide redundancy in case of failures -- that's why they exist. Choosing to go multi-region requires an additional motivation due to the order-of-magnitude additional work required. Why is your organization desiring multi-Region rather than multi-AZ? They will need to have a _very_ strong reason to justify the cost and effort.